# how to add search box on the table in grafana dashboard

Tags: grafana

I have a table. I need to add a search box to get the data based on a column name. how to add a search box in the table panel.im using grafana with sql server plug in.

query

```
SELECT top 1000  * FROM Data
 order by A_id desc
```

Comment: Do you want to use a "WHERE field = value"? The search box will receive the field name or the value? Explain better what you want.

Comment: i dont want to get the results from the sql query, i want a search box on the top of grafana table where i can insert IMEI value. which will filter the table result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See feature was requested, but seems never was implemented https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3919

But you can enable columns filter
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/visualizations/table/filter-table-columns/

Answer (score 1):

To enable filter option open any Grafana dashboard in edit mode.

On the right side panel there is tab called `Table`, under this there is option to enable `column filter`.

Enable it and save it, now you can see filter icon on panel.
Click filter icon to see available options.

[image: Grafana filter option]